# Multer - handle missing file

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I'm using multer as express middleware to upload a file like so:

```
const upload = multer().single('fieldName');

router.post(
  '/',
  upload,
  (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.file) 
  }
);
```

It works fine except when I sent the form without a file. Then apparently the upload middleware is just skipped and `req.file` is  `undefined`.

I tried to add a filter like so but apparently the filter function is not called when there is no file:

```
function fileFilter(req, file, cb) {
  console.log('filtering'); //never reached when file is missing
  if (!file) {
    return cb(new Error('no file', false));
  }
  cb(null, true);
}

const upload = multer({fileFilter: fileFilter}).single('fieldName');

router.post(...)
```

Is there any way to handle the missing file inside the multer middleware? Or do I have to check afterwards?

Comment: Try to add a middleware to verify if file is present after multer() execution. Example: https://gist.github.com/sayhicoelho/f6e2c076a9069b929e07c4e21b768850

Answer (score 0):

check in you html form "fieldName" in input name

and this can you help
in you routes app

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now()+'.mp3')
  }
})
var upload = multer({ storage: storage })

router.post(
  '/uploadfile',upload.single('fieldName'),
)
```

Comment: how to make file upload optional?